# org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=test-user, access=EXECUTE, inode="system":hadoop:test-user:rwx------

Tags: hadoop

Previously test-user used to reside on an edge server to which connectivity was lost. Hence we reconstructed the edge server and have been trying to get it up and running but I keep getting the below error.

```
Job initialization failed: 
org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException:
org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied:
user=test-user, access=EXECUTE,
inode="system":hadoop:test-user:rwx------ at
sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor20.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) at
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:95)
at
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:57)
at
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.<init>(DFSClient.java:3371)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.create(DFSClient.java:743) at
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.create(DistributedFileSystem.java:182)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:557) at
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:538) at
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:445) at
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:437) at
org.apache.hadoop.security.Credentials.writeTokenStorageFile(Credentials.java:169)
at
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress.generateAndStoreTokens(JobInProgress.java:3802)
at
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress.initTasks(JobInProgress.java:970)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.initJob(JobTracker.java:4237)
at
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FairScheduler$JobInitializer$InitJob.run(FairScheduler.java:301)
at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) Caused by:
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException:
org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied:
user=report_generator, access=EXECUTE,
inode="system":hadoop:report_generator:rwx------ at
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:199)
at
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkTraverse(FSPermissionChecker.java:155)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hadoop:test-user:rwx------`  permissions means only the hadoop user can access those files. The `test-user` in the message is a group, not a user. And no group can access the path specified

If `test-user` is not in its own group, then you need to `chown` the path, else, you can `chmod 770`.

Similar error at the end for a different account

`hadoop:report_generator:rwx------`

And these user and groups need to exist on the namenode first, the edge nodes second

Comment: @Bd As explained here, your user (analytics) doesn't have the correct permissions for accessing as admin or supergroup

Comment: @Bd I don't know what your code does. But I do think that anything under /tmp should be globally read-writable, so you could use `hadoop fs -chmod -R 777 /tmp` (as the admin user) to fix it